# Trying to view database table through textview but no display

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to view my database table through textview, but no data is displayed when i click the button, any help would be appreciated

#### employee class

```
onclicklistner
{
Intent viewallemp=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ViewallEMP.class);
            startActivity(viewallemp);
 }
```

#### ViewallEMP class

```
TextView viewallemp=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.showtextView1);

    DBhandle dbhandle=new DBhandle(this);
    dbhandle=dbhandle.open();


    dbhandle.getEMPData();
    String empdata=dbhandle.getEMPData();
    viewallemp.setText(empdata);
```

#### database class

```
public String getEMPData() {
    String[] columns = new String[] { EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, EMP_DOB, EMP_ADDR, EMP_PHONE };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(EMPINFO_TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null,
            null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(EMP_ID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(EMP_NAME);
    int iDOB = c.getColumnIndex(EMP_DOB);
    int iADDR = c.getColumnIndex(EMP_ADDR);
    int iPHONE = c.getColumnIndex(EMP_PHONE);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iName)
                + " " + c.getString(iDOB) + " " + c.getString(iADDR)+ " " + c.getString(iPHONE) + "\n";
    }
 return result;
  }
```

following data is stored in database

[image: data in database]

Comment: you need to return your result

Comment: have look at `Realm` database, it's easy

Comment: show total getEmpData method?

Comment: Your code looks correct, check whether your `textview` is vissible, and also check you have returned the correct data from `getEmpData()` method.

Comment: @Madhu i just edited my query "return result" is there in code, sorry about that

Comment: did your cursor count is more than 0 ???

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some issues in this method return type.

Try to return result.

```
public String getEMPData() {

String[] columns = new String[] { EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, EMP_DOB, EMP_ADDR, EMP_PHONE };
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(EMPINFO_TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null,
        null, null);
String result = "";

int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(EMP_ID);
int iName = c.getColumnIndex(EMP_NAME);
int iDOB = c.getColumnIndex(EMP_DOB);
int iADDR = c.getColumnIndex(EMP_ADDR);
int iPHONE = c.getColumnIndex(EMP_PHONE);

for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
    result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iName)
            + " " + c.getString(iDOB) + " " + c.getString(iADDR)+ " " + c.getString(iPHONE) + "\n";
}
```

Comment: Do you think this will make sense?

Answer (score 0):

**Try String Buffer insted of String**

```
public String getEMPData() {
            String[] columns = new String[] { EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, EMP_DOB, EMP_ADDR, EMP_PHONE };
            Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(EMPINFO_TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null,
                    null, null);
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(EMP_ID);
            int iName = c.getColumnIndex(EMP_NAME);
            int iDOB = c.getColumnIndex(EMP_DOB);
            int iADDR = c.getColumnIndex(EMP_ADDR);
            int iPHONE = c.getColumnIndex(EMP_PHONE);

            for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
                sb.append(c.getString(iRow) + " ");
                sb.append(c.getString(iName) + " ");
                sb.append(c.getString(iDOB) + " ");
                sb.append(c.getString(iADDR) + " ");
                sb.append(c.getString(iPHONE) + " ");

            }
           return sb.toString();
        }
```

Comment: This should be comment, not an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the following lines

```
for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
    result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iName)
            + " " + c.getString(iDOB) + " " + c.getString(iADDR)+ " " + c.getString(iPHONE) + "\n";
}
```

As

```
if (c != null ) {
    if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
          do {
              result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iName)
              + " " + c.getString(iDOB) + " " + c.getString(iADDR)+ " " + c.getString(iPHONE) + "\n";
          }while (c.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you..

Comment: May I know what is the problem?

Comment: m new to android pls dont mind if its childish but how check whether your textview is vissible and the problem is that when i click the button **viewallEMP** class is started but data is not shown

Comment: I can't get you? And I don't mind because everyone have problems at startup. Tell me clearly.

Comment: sir what i mean to is that my code use to work before

Comment: You got the output, right? Why can't you get it before? What error you are facing? Don't use `sir`. We are friends :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81237/discussion-between-sajjan-and-gunaseelan).